# While Inserting the 3rd node in my linked list my code seems to timeout

Tags: c, linked-list

I am learning Linked Lists in C. So I found a project online which will help give you experience with linked list.

You have to create a C file which take a few commands as string. I for Insert, P for Print , D for delete, S for search and Q for quit.

Whenever I try to insert the third node and press enter in the terminal the code seems to time out.

It is possible I have circularly connected the list somewhere but I am unable to spot the error.

I will appreciate some guidance and support here!

```
    int main(void) 
    {
        // Declare the head of the linked list.
        Node *head = NULL;
        
        char *songName, *artist, *genre;
        
        artist = (char *) malloc(MAX_LENGTH * sizeof (char));
        genre = (char *) malloc(MAX_LENGTH * sizeof (char));
        songName = (char*) malloc(MAX_LENGTH * sizeof (char));
        
        // Announce at the start of the program
        printf("Personal Music Library.\n\n");
        printf("%s", "Commands are I (insert), D (delete), S (search by song name),\n" //I have removed the code for the other commands
               "P (print), Q (quit).\n");
    
        char response;
        
        char input[MAX_LENGTH + 1];
        
        do 
        {
            inputStringFromUser("\nCommand", input, MAX_LENGTH); // Response is the first character entered by user.
            response = toupper(input[0]); // Convert to uppercase to simplify later comparisons.
    
            if (response == 'I') // Insert a song into the linked list and order it alphabeticallly by song name.
            {
                char *promptName = "Song name";
                char *promptArtist = "Artist";
                char *promptGenre = "Genre";
    
                inputStringFromUser(promptName, songName, MAX_LENGTH);
                inputStringFromUser(promptArtist, artist, MAX_LENGTH);
                inputStringFromUser(promptGenre, genre, MAX_LENGTH);
                
                if (!songAlreadyInList(head, songName)) 
                {
                    head = insertNewNode(head, songName, artist, genre);
                } 
                
                else
                {
                    songNameDuplicate(songName);
                }
            }
} while (response != 'Q'); // Delete the entire linked list.

void inputStringFromUser(char *prompt, char *s, int maxStrLength) 
{
    int i = 0;
    char c;

    printf("%s --> ", prompt);
    while (i < maxStrLength && (c = getchar()) != '\n')
        s[i++] = c;
    s[i] = '\0';
}
    Node *insertNewNode(Node *head, char songName[MAX_LENGTH], char artist[MAX_LENGTH], char genre[MAX_LENGTH]) 
    {
        Node *next = head; //to insert first node
        if (head == NULL || strcmp(head -> songName, songName) > 0) 
        {
            Node *insert = (Node *) malloc( sizeof(Node));
            insert -> songName = (char *) malloc(MAX_LENGTH * sizeof(char));
            insert -> artist = (char *) malloc(MAX_LENGTH * sizeof(char));
            insert -> genre = (char *) malloc(MAX_LENGTH * sizeof(char));
            if (insert != NULL) 
            {
                strcpy(insert -> songName, songName);
                strcpy(insert -> artist, artist);
                strcpy(insert -> genre, genre);
                insert -> next = next;
            }
            return insert;
        }
        
        Node *current = head;
        //to insert in the order
        while (current -> next != NULL && strcmp(current -> next -> songName, songName) < 0) 
        {
            current = current -> next;
        }
        
        Node *insert = (Node *) malloc(sizeof (Node));
        insert -> songName = (char *) malloc(MAX_LENGTH * sizeof (char));
        insert -> artist = (char *) malloc(MAX_LENGTH * sizeof (char));
        insert -> genre = (char *) malloc(MAX_LENGTH * sizeof (char));
        if (insert != NULL) 
        {
            strcpy(insert -> songName, songName);
            strcpy(insert -> artist, artist);
            strcpy(insert -> genre, genre);
            insert -> next = next;
        }
        current -> next = insert;
        return head;
    }
```

Comment: Could you update your code to include a [MCVE]?

Comment: When you create the link for your new node: `insert -> next = next;`, the value of `next` is still the `head`. You've inadvertently created a circular list and when you insert a song, you are iterating it in an infinite loop. Get rid of `next` and set `insert->next = current->next`.

Comment: (Aside: Your tests for `(insert != NULL)` are useful, but they come too late. At the time you test the pointer, you have already dereferenced it via the `->` operator.)

Comment: The reason we ask for a [mre] so we don't have spend time to look at code that isn't relevant to the problem, yet complete so we can reproduce the issue.  This is what this community expect of you.  In your case,  include a `main()` but remove the `artist` and `genre` attributes as they don't add anything.  Minimizing is a very effective troubleshooting technique for your own sake, too.

Comment: @SeanF I deleted the older question so I dont get some time ban on my account.

Comment: @AGsims Post a [mcve] to improve this question.  Include input used and a `main()`.

Comment: @MOehm Yes I can see how that created a infinite loop. could you help me understand your second comment.

Comment: @AllanWind Thank you I will keep that in mind and put it to practice.

Comment: I have updated the code with the MRE

Comment: Updated is better yet does not compile.  Input used missing.

Comment: `artist = (char *) malloc(MAX_LENGTH * sizeof (char));` and friends are 1 too small for `inputStringFromUser()`.

Comment: Well, `insert` goes between `current` and `current->next`, which may well be ´NULL`. To acieve that, `current->next` must point to `insert` and `insert->next` must point to the old value of `current->next`. (I find that visualizing such things with sketched boxes and arrows on scrap paper helps.) Of course, you must make the second assignment first, so that you can access the old value of `insert->next`.

Comment: You can test for a cycle; _eg_ using [Floyd's cycle finding algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Floyd's_tortoise_and_hare). It may be useful in debugging, especially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a working implementation that fixes the following issues:

1. eliminate duplication of node creation by using a separate function. This also makes the pointer tweaking much easier to follow as it's now just a few lines of code.
2. no need to cast the return value of malloc
3. check all malloc returns and handle cleanup (not leaking memory)
4. you update head, but you need to update what head points to (so need address of head)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_LENGTH 10

typedef struct Node Node;
struct Node {
    char *songName;
    Node *next;
};


Node *createNode(char songName[MAX_LENGTH]) {
    Node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(*newNode));
    if(!newNode) {
        printf("malloc failed\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    // simplifies error handling with more attributes
    newNode->songName = NULL;

    newNode->songName = malloc(MAX_LENGTH);
    if(!newNode->songName) {
        printf("malloc failed\n");
        goto err;
    }
    strcpy(newNode->songName, songName);
    newNode->next = NULL;

    return newNode;
err:
    free(newNode->songName);
    free(newNode);
    return 0;
}


Node *insertNode(Node **head, Node *newNode) {
    if(!head || !newNode) return NULL;

    if(!*head) {
        *head = newNode;
    } else {
        Node *current;
        for(current = *head; current->next; current = current->next);
        current->next = newNode;
    }
    return *head;
}

void printNodes(Node *head) {
    for(Node *current = head; current; current = current->next) {
        printf("%s\n", current->songName);
    }
}

int main() {
    Node *head = NULL;
    insertNode(&head, createNode("hello"));
    insertNode(&head, createNode("world"));
    printNodes(head);
}
```

Comment: (OP's insert function returns the new head. I prefer the pointer to node pointer variant, too, but `head = insert(head, stuff)` is a valid, if redundant, function signature.)

Comment: Thank you. I will understand and try to write it on my own.

Comment: @AGsims If you can tweak the signature you can improve things.  insertNode() now returns the head, but if it returned the tail you insert in constant time otherwise you have to search from the head on every call.  Now that I introduced `createNode()` you could require the head to be valid linked list, so this means `insertNode()` also have a single path of inserting into valid linked list.